# Copy A path in powershell that it generates

Tags: path, copy, powercfg

4.1 when you run

**PS C:\Users\tjhopkin> powercfg /batteryreport**

*---IT creates the path bellow----*

**Battery life report saved to file path C:\Users\tjhopkin\battery-report.html.**

I want to create a line in power shell that will copy that line then start it to open it right away for any computer - the paths change per computer. So the next line of code needs to copy that path then the next needs to start that path.

I have gotten it to work for my computer using me adding the path fisacaly but every computer saves paths differently and in deferent locations.

Please help.

Comment: I have also tried this New-Item -Path "C:\Reports" -Type Directory -end
powercfg /batteryreport /output "C:\Reports"
start "C:\Reports"

Comment: This forces it to create a fold in c drive no mater what and then run the powercfg but for some reason it wont run that even though it says it is

Comment: New-Item -Path "C:\Reports" -Type Directory 
powercfg /batteryreport /output "C:\Reports\battery.html"
start "C:\Reports\battery.html"